# Windows Batch: How to read date and time in a file and compare it to current date and time

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, time, comparison

I currently have a batch script which saves the current date time into a log file.

Note: I got this script from a microsoft forum since i dont know how to create batch scripts. Although I know how to develop with java, which i do not wish to do in this case.

```
@echo off  
REM *DATETIME.BAT 
REM *Copy date and time to create a new log file 
echo.|date>datetime.tmp  
echo.|time>>datetime.tmp 
IF NOT EXIST datetime.tmp GOTO Error1 
type datetime.tmp|FIND "current">datetime.log  
rem del datetime.tmp 
GOTO End 

:Error1 
Echo.  
Echo There was an error processing the command.  
Echo Unable to find temporary sort file DATETIME.TMP.  
Echo.  
GOTO End 

:End
```

I can understand how this code works and the output in the logfile is this for example:

```
The current date is: 01.01.2018 
The current time is: 13:01:17,42
```

What I want to know is: How can I read the date and time in **another** script and check if the current time is 1h greater than the saved time and/or if the current date is at least 1 day later. There should be a specific return value if the conditions are true or untrue respectively.

I hope I was able to explain my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Providing the second line of `datetime.tmp` would be useful because the example you have given does not show us which is `dd` and which is `mm` e.g. `Enter the new date: (mm.dd.yy)`

Answer (score 0):

This is something I wrote that is a combination of batch and vbscript (to get yesterday's date), you can do an `if` statement and match if date == previous date, you can do a similar thing with time.

```
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
 del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
 set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
 set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
 set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
 set "result=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%"
 echo %result%
pause
```